# Redirect NiFi Azure AD OAuth Request usinig NGINX

Tags: nginx, azure-active-directory, apache-nifi, nginx-location, nginx-config

I have been plugging away at this for a good number of days now and I have been unable to find a solution. We have deployed NiFi onto an HDInsight cluster Edge Node, which comes with NGINX (free) pre-installed. We have installed NiFi onto this node and had the basic, unsecured NiFi UI being served by NGINX. So far, so good.

The requirement is that NiFi be secured using Azure AD and it is this that is giving me issues. The problem is that no matter what I try, I am unable to configure NGINX such that it redirects the OAuth request from NiFi to https://login.microsoftonline.com. The closest I have got is to redirect to the required domain, and include the query string, but missing the location part of the URL (AD tenant ID), which means authentication fails.

So my question is how can I configure NGINX to correctly redirect the OAuth request? I am either able to get:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/?client_id=<ID>&response_type=code&scope=openid+email&state=4bibmlfesmgbmi9o1p8blibd4q&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F<NODE HOSTNAME>%3A443%2Fnifi-api%2Faccess%2Foidc%2Fcallback
```

or

```
https://<NODE HOSTNAME>/<TENANT ID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<ID>&response_type=code&scope=openid+email&state=4bibmlfesmgbmi9o1p8blibd4q&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fems-poc-tri-hdi-nfi.apps.azurehdinsight.net%3A443%2Fnifi-api%2Faccess%2Foidc%2Fcallback
```

I am unable to get:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT ID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<ID>&response_type=code&scope=openid+email&state=4bibmlfesmgbmi9o1p8blibd4q&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fems-poc-tri-hdi-nfi.apps.azurehdinsight.net%3A443%2Fnifi-api%2Faccess%2Foidc%2Fcallback
```

I have tried all sorts, but I have finally had to admit defeat. The current NGINX config is given below:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 1024;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
    rewrite_log on;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    #upstream nifi {
    #    server 10.1.0.10:9443;
    #    keepalive 512;
    #}

    server
    {
        listen 443 default_server;
        #server_name localhost;
        server_name ems-poc-tri-hdi-nfi.apps.azurehdinsight.net;
        proxy_set_header X-ProxyHost ems-poc-tri-hdi-nfi.apps.azurehdinsight.net;
        proxy_set_header X-ProxyScheme https;
        proxy_set_header X-ProxyPort 443;

        location = / {
            return 301 https://10.1.0.10:9443/nifi;
        }
        location /nifi {
            proxy_pass https://10.1.0.10:9443/nifi;
        }
        location /nifi-api {
            proxy_pass https://10.1.0.10:9443/nifi-api;
        }
        location ~ "\/<AAD TENANT ID>" {
            access_log /var/log/nginx/special.access.log;
            proxy_set_header Host login.microsoftonline.com;
            add_header X-uri "$uri";
            add_header X-host "$host";
            add_header X-request_uri "$request_uri";
            add_header X-args "$args";

            if ($request_uri ~ "/[^?]+\?[^?]+callback$") {
                #return 307 https://login.microsoftonline.com$uri?$args&redirect=true;
                #rewrite ^(?<location>/[^?]+) $location redirect;
                #rewrite ^(?<location>/[^?]+) https://login.microsoftonline.com$location redirect;
                rewrite ^ $scheme://login.microsoftonline.com$uri?$args&redirect=true? last;
            }


            if ($request_uri ~ "/[^?]+\?[^?]+true$") {
                #    proxy_pass https://login.microsoftonline.com;
                rewrite ^ https://login.microsoftonline.com last;
                #return 307 https://login.microsoftonline.com$uri?$args;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you referred to https://sweetcode.io/authentication-applications-azure-active-directory-2/?

Comment: @TonyJu Never heard of it, so no. I have installed the binary and followed the suggested configuration on the site mentioned, but I've not been able to get any further than getting the "Sign in with Azure account" screen - clicking the button takes me nowhere. Are you able to provide an example, real-life configuration?